# Perl open() and grep

Tags: perl

OK, so I've noticed some counter intuitive behavior of grep in perl, depending on how I open a file.  If I open a file read only, (<) it works.  If I open it read-write, (+<), it works, but if I open it append-read, it does not.  (+>>)

I'm sure this can be worked around, but I'm curious as to why it works this way.  Anyone have a good explanation?

Given a `test.txt` file of:

```
a
b
c
```

and a `greptest.pl` file of:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(RFILE, '<', "test.txt")
    or die "Read failed: $!";
if(grep /b/, <RFILE>) {print "Found when opened read\n";}
    else {print "Not found when opened read\n";}
close RFILE;

open(RWFILE, '+<', "test.txt")
    or die "Write-read failed: $!";
if(grep /b/, <RWFILE>) {print "Found when opened write-read\n";}
    else {print "Not found when opened write-read\n";}
close RWFILE;

open(AFILE, '+>>', "test.txt")
    or die "Append-read failed: $!";
if(grep /b/, <AFILE>) {print "Found when opened append-read\n";}
    else {print "Not found when opened append-read\n";}
close AFILE;
```

Running it returns following:

```
$ ./greptest.pl 
Found when opened read
Found when opened write-read
Not found when opened append-read
```

Whereas I would have expected it to find on all three tests.

Comment: My best guess is that grep only searches from the file pointer onward, and when you open it in append the file pointer is set to the end of the file.

Comment: Solid guess, at least.  But why would `+<` be different from `+>>`.  Both append to the end of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File handle would be at the end of the file for append mode.

Comment: Fair enough.  Any good reason why the file handle isn't at the end of the file for `+<` mode, which also appends?

Comment: Since you are opening read-write, it assumes you want to read from the file as well. You shouldn't have to rewind a pointer to do that.

Comment: print tell FILEHANDLE will tell you where the position of filehandle is 

0
0
6 for rfile, rwfile, afile respectively for your case.

Comment: `+<` overwrites from the beginning of the file, unless you `seek` to somewhere else